# Cassandra writes only 4789 rows when loading using Spark

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-spark, hdfs

I have Cassandra installed on single node AWS. I am trying to bulkload 1mn rows(70MB) of CSV file from HDFS to Cassandra via Spark. But i noticed that cassandra only writes 4789 rows. Should i have to change any properties in Spark or Cassandra?

```
$ hadoop fs -ls par.txt
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
-rw-------   3 u**** u****     707531 2015-09-24 10:33 par.txt
```

Cassandra Table:

```
CREATE TABLE party1 (
  id text,
  country text,
  email text,
  first_name text,
  ip_address text,
  last_name text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

cqlsh:cassdb> select count(*) from party1;

 count
-------
  4789

(1 rows)
```

Spark Commands:

```
val cassing = sc.textFile("par.txt").map(line => line.split(",")).map(p => (p(0),p(1),p(2),p(3),p(4),p(5)))

scala> cassing.saveToCassandra("cassdb", "party1", SomeColumns("id","first_name","last_name","email","country","ip_address"))
```

Comment: does it throw any exception while uploading?

Comment: No it doesn't.. Spark just completes the job syccessfully

Comment: Cassendra logs are written at `/var/log/cassandra/` (default location). If you have already checked the logs for any obvious fault, then you should check your data, if it is correctly map around the line number - its type and other restrictions. Cassendra does not have such limitation.

Comment: I am actually using a spark-Cassandra connector to connect both. I got some options to control output.batch.size.rows and output.batch.size.bytes and etc etc. I tried all but in vain.